# Any "smart" network design tools out there?

Tags: networking, planning

I'm currently looking for the right tool for planning a large industrial network, that offers some more functionality than drawing nodes and connections (like in Visio etc.). I've already tested SolarWinds Network Topology Mapper, but as nice at it is, it only works with existing networks.

I would like to layout the network with all its hosts and infrastructure components, routers, switches, MPLS, VLANS etc. and be able to switch the view between the different network layers, maybe up to IP.

Ideally, the tool would be able to detect address conflicts, unwanted switching loops etc.